# How to navigate to CPT archive from listed taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Custom Post Type templates hierarchy for a CPT called `idea` like

```
page-ideas.php

taxonomy.php
taxonomy-ideas.php

single.php
single-idea.php

archive.php
archive-idea.php
```

I am facing an issue on navigating to CPT Archive (list of all Custom Post type under this term) from taxonomy term listed in a custom page template. In `all-ideas` custom page template I have

```
<?php 
/*
 Template Name: Ideas
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div class="container">
<?php
$tax = 'ideas';
$terms = get_terms( $tax, $args = array(   'hide_empty' => false,  ));
?>
    <div class="row">
<?php
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
  echo '<div class="col-4"> <a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '"> <div class="card my-2"> <div class="card-body">  ' . $term->name .' </div> </div>  </a></div>';
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is listing all Terms but when I click on the term I am landing in First Custom Post Type Single instead of getting list of Custom post type based on this term. In `archive.php` and `archive-idea.php` I have

**archive.php**

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
    This is all Archive
    <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

**archive-idea.php**

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
    This is all Idea Archive
    <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: When writing titles, please do not add "Issue", it is entirely redundant. The system prevents the word "problem" for this reason, and perhaps this synonym should be added. Everything is an issue. Titles make more sense for current and future readers if they are asked as a question in English: "How do I foo the bar in WordPress". Sentence case is preferred over title case these days.

Comment: When writing the body of your question, try to observe the correct case rules for English. If Everything Is Capitalised Then It Is Harder To Read and readers may decline to help (and volunteer editors won't be pleased at further repair work).

Comment: Please do not beg on this platform. Readers appreciate a succinct expression of the problem, and they will respond if they find the problem interesting. They are not more likely to help if you plead and scrape and curtsey (and for readers who like to answer questions, it is exhausting to be the target of persistent pleading). I have [more information on this theme here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391945).