# How to add item to class list of objects populated in an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have a class `Team` like

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>();
    
    public Team(string name, IEnumerable<Player> players)
    {
        Name = name;
        Players = players;
    }
    
    public void addPlayer(Player pl){
     // Players.Add(pl);
    }
}
```

How can I properly create a method to add a player to the team class like:

```
 public void addPlayer(Player pl){
     // Players.Add(pl);
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Why did you decide to make `Players` to be of type `IEnumerable<Player>`?

Comment: Change the type from `IEnumerable<Player>` to `IList<Player>` or `ICollection<Player>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add an item to a IEnumerable<T> collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210295/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-ienumerablet-collection)

Comment: A quick reminder about the begging tone in your questions, Behseini ([my recent feedback is in these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293794/how-to-navigate-to-cpt-archive-from-listed-taxonomy-term#comment117239926_66293794)). On this occasion, it drew my attention to the fact that the question is off-topic anyway. The moral of the story is perhaps to listen to advice that will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really need a property to be publically (i.e. from the outside of your class) settable, don't make it public. An [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0) is a read-only type, you cannot add elements to it. However, you can add elements to a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0).

Convert your auto-property to a property with a backing field and then access the field inside your class, but use the property for public reading of the players:

```
public class Team
{
    private readonly List<Player> players;

    public string Name { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Player> Players => this.players;
    // older versions of C#: Players { get { return this.players; } }
    
    public Team(string name, List<Player> players)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.players = players;
    }
    
    public void addPlayer(Player pl) {
        this.players.Add(pl);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills you are right. I'll update the answer to use a concrete `List<T>`, since it is only used privately anyway

Comment: thanks @knittl but I am getting error on constructor `Players = players;` complaining that the `Players` is read only!

Comment: @Behseini whoops, that was a leftover from the original code. You need to assign the backing field, not the property

Comment: Technically, exposing it as an `IEnumerable` doesn't make it read only. The backing object is still a `List` and you can type cast it as such and mess with it any way you want. If you want something to be actually read only you need to use `.AsReadOnly()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add to `Players` because it is an `IEnumerable`. Only specific kinds of `IEnumerable`, such as lists and sets, can be added to. Here's one way your code can break: I (a user of your class) can set `Player` to an `IEnumerable` that you can't add things to:

```
var team = new Team("My Team", new Player[] { });
team.AddPlayer(new Player(...));
```

Now `Player` is an array, which you certainly can't add to!

To allow adding things to `Players`, you need to choose an type that allows adding. For example, an `ICollection<Player>`, `IList<Player>`, or `List<Player>`.

```
public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
public Team(string name, IEnumerable<Player> players)
    Name = name;
    Players = players.ToList();
}

// uncommenting the line in AddPlayer will now compile
```

You can make a private `player` field of this type, and still expose a `IEnumerable<Player>` if you want. But you need to remove the setter:

```
private List<Player> players;
public IEnumerable<Player> Players => players;
public Team(string name, IEnumerable<Player> players)
    Name = name;
    this.players = players.ToList();
}

public void addPlayer(Player pl){
    players.Add(pl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add anything in an object of type `IEnumerable<T>`. The reason is that `IEnumerable<T>` [essentially](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0).

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type.

That you need is a Collection. Possibly a `List<T>`.

E.g.

```
public class Team
{
    // Make essentially readonly these properties
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; }

    public Team(string name, List<Player> players)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(name)} cannot be null or empty");
        }
        Name = name;
    
        Players = player ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(players));
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player pl)
    {
        Players.Add(pl);
    }
}
```

Note: that I have placed also some checks in the constructor, in order we verify that the object is created is in a consistent state (a team without a name, wouldn't be a team).