# Property returns null using C# expression bodied in construction

Tags: c#

I am trying to find out why I am getting `null` in console. As you can see I am initializing the object at `public Student() => name = "Foo";` but I am getting `null`

```
using System;  
  
namespace Tutorial  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            Student st = new Student();  
            Console.WriteLine(st.Name);
        }  
    }  
  
    public class Student
    {
       private string name;
       public Student() => name = "Foo";
       public string Name
       {
          get; set;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a field name and a property Name - both are independent - and you only set the field inside the constructor. So the property Name is still null when you read it.

Comment: This is a great chance to learn how to use the debugger. Put breakpoints on the Student constructor, on both the `Name` getter and setter, and on the first line of `Main` (where you construct `st`). Press F5 to start your program. When it stops put both `name` and `Name` in a watch window. Step through (F10). Note that the `Name` getter is called, but the setter never gets called. Keep an eye on the watch window. When you are in the Name getter, look at the call stack

Comment: A quick reminder about the begging tone in your questions, Behseini ([my recent feedback is in these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293794/how-to-navigate-to-cpt-archive-from-listed-taxonomy-term#comment117239926_66293794)).

Comment: Your last contribution was auto-deleted by the abuse filter.

Comment: Meanwhile you might want to take a look at the reception on this question: three close votes and three downvotes (I have not voted on this question). So you have a choice: you can take this feedback into account in your next question, or you can carry on getting a poor reception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-property is not being initialized with a value, so that's why you are getting null.

It might be important to show the difference between fields and properties.

```
public class Student
{
    // This is a field. It stores the actual data
    private string name;

    // This is an auto-property. The actual private field cannot be accessed directly.
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    // This is a manual property which exposes a getter and a setter for the private field.
    public string NameProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So, you've got several options. You might want just get rid of the field like so:

```
public class Student
{
   public Student() => Name = "Foo";
   public string Name
   {
      get; set;
   }
}
```